# How to calculate differences based on grouping values in another column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have multiple datasets with a grouping column containing names of plant roots (Rname) and a column indicating the day of the year when the root was detected (with each of these days indicating a measuring session during an experiment - there were up to six sessions in total). Here is a sample of the data:

[image]

I want to find the total lifetime of the root over these sessions, which I am hoping to achieve by simply subtracting the day of the year when the root was first detected from the day of the year of last detection (as shown in the image).

I am not proficient with Excel, and I don't really know how to code a macro or do any fancy stuff like that. I need to do this for about 70 separate spreadsheets, and it would be near impossible to calculate this manually for each and every root. Is there any way to do this automatically with a helper column or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

## My solution

First, keep your columns `A` and `B` sorted in ascending order.

Then, assuming that row 1 is a header row, set

`C2` to `=IF(NOT(A2=A1),ROW(),0)`;

`D2` to `=IF(AND(NOT(C2=C1),NOT(C2=0)),CONCATENATE("B",TEXT(C2,"0")),D1)`;

`E2` to `=IF(NOT(A3=A2),ROW(),0)`;

`F2` to `=IF(AND(NOT(E2=E1),NOT(E2=0)),CONCATENATE("B",TEXT(E2,"0")),F3)`;

and, finally, `G2` to `=INDIRECT(F2)-INDIRECT(D2)`.

Autofill columns `C` through `G` to the last row, and you get the lifetime of root Ax in cell Gx.

Here is the output with your sample data:

[image]

## Explanations

Sort the first two columns to ensure that data are grouped by roots, and the last data minus the first data in each group is this root's lifetime.

Use two supplementary columns (C & D) to find the cell index of the first data, and another two to find index of the last data.

The trick is that each time you observe the value of column A changes, you know that a data group has ended and a new one begun.

After filling columns D and F with cell indexes, use INDIRECT function to fetch the respective value and subtract them.

## Reference

[TEXT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885)

[INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474B3A3A-8A26-4F44-B491-92B6306FA261)

Answer (score 1):

In general, one would probably expect that the days and number of measurements would *not* be the same for every root group.  The formula below gives the correct results when the days and number of measurements vary.

`=IF(A2<>A3,MAX(IF(A:A=A2,B:B,FALSE))-MIN(IF(A:A=A2,B:B,FALSE)),"")`

This is an array formula and must be entered in C2 with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  After it's entered, click on C2 and fill down to the last row of your data.  The table below shows the results:

[image]

How it works:  The inner expressions `IF(A:A=A2,B:B,FALSE)` return an array of the values in Column B where Column A = An (the particular R Name in the current row) and FALSE everywhere else.  So the Days of the Year are isolated for each R Name, whatever they are and no matter how many there are.  Then the Life is calculated by subtracting the Min from the Max of that array.

The outer IF() puts the Life calculation at the end of a group of R Names and blank everywhere else.

Hope this helps, and good luck.

Answer (score -1):

@Dunius, I would like to suggest you the immediate solution,its like **group Subtraction**. And It's working properly using your data.

[image]

Since for each set of codes you have a lowest and a highest day of the year value.

So my **Solution** is,

=IF($A201<>$A200,(MAX(B$200:B200)-MIN(B$200:B200)),"")

Drag down the formula.

And give me some time so create VBA code for the same job.

**NB: Formula in cell C200. Please change the data range as you need.**

Comment: Thank you so much for your elegant solution - I hope this works. Would it also work with varying ranges? (Not all roots have 6 sessions, for instance, and I think the sample I posted did not show this)

Comment: This solution won't work unless the days are the same for every Root Group.  It takes the Max-Min of the entire Column B for every root group.  I'll post an answer with a fairly simple (array) formula.

Comment: Dunois, Yes My formula will work even the range may vary.

Answer (score -1):

**@Dunois,** I would like to suggest two solutions. First one is related to previous post and second one is improvised.

**Solution 1:**

In regard of previous post, **your question was whether the Formula will work for variable length data or not?**

Yes it will work. Check the screen shot **Root3 has 7 rows** and the Formula is simply dragged to the length, which is,

=IF($A201<>$A200,(MAX(B$200:B200)-MIN(B$200:B200)),"")

[image]

**NB:** The data range is **A200 to C218**(excluding Header row). Formula cell is **C200**.
Adjust the data rage as your need.

**Solution 2:**

It’s an improvised one. For this the data range need to be Sorted and apply the Group command, and finally use the following Formula.

=IF(F200="",MAX(G200:INDEX(G$199:G199,MATCH(2,1/(G$199:$G199=""),1)))-MIN(G200:INDEX(G$199:G199,MATCH(2,1/(G$199:$G199=""),1))),"")

[image]

**NB:** Data range is **F200 to H218**(excluding Header row) . Formula is in cell **H200**.

Also, **purposely I've eliminated to Heading from G199**.

If you want to avoid it write the Headings in row 199 and start the first entry from row 201 and don't forget to alter the cell address in the Formula.

Adjust the data rage as your need.